# Unable to connect to openfin runtime using openfin java adapter

Tags: openfin

I have been trying to connect to the openfin runtime using openfin java adapter. I am not specifying any port to connect to. I am also providing my own implementation of DesktopStateListener with the methods onReady, onClose, onError, onMessage, onOutgoingMessage. But when I call `connect` method for some reason the connection is not established and none of these methods are being called as well. It doesn't show any stacktrace about any possible exception as well. I am stuck in this scenario and not sure how to proceed further. Can someone tell me how I can figure this out.

I have been following the below openfin document

https://developer.openfin.co/docs/java/latest/

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing an instance of the [RuntimeConfiguration object](https://developer.openfin.co/docs/java/latest/)
as seen in the documentation [here](https://developers.openfin.co/of-docs/docs/java-api)? To launch and connect to a runtime, I believe this needs to be passed into the `connect` method in order to resolve download and launch runtime to be connected to.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes I am providing instance of RuntimeConfiguration. Even if the connection fails there should be some error thrown, right? I do not get any error as well. Any idea?

Comment: @SathiyaNarayanan, would you happen to have a GitHub link to a repository with code that is failing to establish a runtime connection?